# 0xC0000005: Access violation writing in loaction

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

My programs gives an error if i dont include HeapAlloc.What exactly is happening i cannot understand.

```
int iIndex=0;

enum EDataType
{
    kINT,
    kFLOAT,
    kUINT
};
typedef  struct logstr
{
    EDataType sData_Type;
    string    sComment;
    bool      bStatus;
    float     fDump_Value;
    int       iDump_Value;
    UINT32    uDump_Value;
}slog,*StrLog;

Str_Dump[iIndex]->sData_Type=EDataType(0);//i get a error on this line exception0xC0000005: Access violation writing in location0X00000;
```

But when I include the line

```
Str_Dump[iIndex]=(StrLog)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,sizeof(slog));
```

Then again run the program runs succesfully.

What exactly that line doing? I cannot understand.

I have declared strdump as

```
StrLog Str_Dump[100];
```

Comment: have you allocated space for Str_Dump? it's unclear from this code if this is being done

Comment: @PeskyGnat strdump declaration is like StrLog Str_Dump[100];

Comment: @hardyz009 Yes, but `StrLog` is a pointer, so you only have an array of pointers. You must allocate memory and initialize those pointers  so they point to something. (or, you  could declare an array of `slog` instead of pointers to an `slog`. Also, typedef'ing like this hides the fact that `StrLog` is a pointer, and should be avoided in most cases)

Answer (score 4):

The second line allocates memory for `Str_Dump[iIndex]`. `HeapAlloc` and `GetProcessHeap` are WinApi methods, you can find their documentation on the MSDN website.

The first line crashes because you're accessing an unallocated pointer - `Str_Dump[iIndex]`.

Comment: I am declaring strdump as StrLog Str_Dump[100];

Comment: @hardyz009: That defines a hundred pointers, all unallocated. The first of those, `Str_Dump[0]` is just as unallocated as the last, `Str_Dump[99]`

Answer (score 3):

Well, based on what we can see, it looks like `Str_Dump` is an array of pointers to `slog` objects. Naturally, if you don't create `slog` objects for those pointers to point to (that's what the `HeapAlloc` call does) bad things are going to happen. What's not to understand?